# Why can't rsync be used in place of IMAP/POP?

Tags: linux, ssh, email, rsync, imap

Disclaimer: this relates to those who like to manage their email as files, using the likes of `mutt` or some other maildir reader.

Before I became familiar with the likes of `rsync` and `scp`, IMAP and POP seemed pretty intuitive to me: they just copy mail from the server, and in the case of IMAP, copies of the mail are also left on the server.

However, having learned of `rsync` a few years ago, it struck me that it could just be used to copy a maildir to the client directly.

Am I crazy, or does this basically mean I can use `rsync` instead of programs like `mpop` or `fetchmail`?  The mail-specific copying programs introduce a lot of complexity: certificate checks, mail passwords, etc.  I manage my mail on my own server, and I'm the only tenant on that server.  Would `rsync` work here or is there anything else that `mpop` or `fetchmail` do that I'm not aware of?  Even on multi-tenanted systems, I could also see `rsync` being a good mail copy-er, e.g. in the same way GitHub allows SSH-based retrieval.

Added bonus: I can close more ports on my server, improving security.

Comment: As in unix-world everything is `file` I tend to support your train of thought. As mail-tools are specific, they may add some convenience when needed, `rsync` is a more generic approach, which in some cases may be preferable. I think. Have you tried it already?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Have you tried using rsync to do this yet? It seems like it would be pretty simple for you to test yourself.

Comment: @music2myear I was basically looking for any potential 'gotchas' before trying it myself.  Knowing if anyone else has tried it, and whether there are no later headaches, was mainly what I was after.  I will definitely be trying it, but I wanted to see first if I was missing anything obvious.  E.g. I know the maildir format does stuff with filename suffixes, and I was wondering if this might throw up any problems while using plain rsync.

Comment: Please read our Help section. What you want is not the sort of question we entertain here.